# How to define a keyed (grouped) join in data table?

Tags: r, data.table

I would like to overload the `[.data.table` operator so that grouped joins can be achieved. I will use `dplyr` to illustrate what I mean by a grouped join. Take for example the function below that wraps around `dplyr::inner_join`:

```
inner_join_grp <- function(x, y, by = NULL, copy = FALSE, suffix = c(".x", ".y"), 
                           ...) {
    stopifnot(identical(group_vars(x), group_vars(y)))


    grp <- group_vars(x)

    by <- c(by, grp)

    return(inner_join(x, y, by, copy, suffix, ...))
}
```

All this function does is to check that input data.frames `x` and `y` have the same groups, and if they do, to add the grouping variables to the join key specified by `by = ...`.

An application would be like this:

```
n_grp <- 5
n_grp2 <- 3

set.seed(0)

tmp_df <-
    data.frame(grp = rep(letters[1:n_grp2], each = n_grp),
               grp2 = rep(1:n_grp, times = n_grp2),
               x = runif(n_grp * n_grp2))

tmp_df_2 <-
    data.frame(grp = rep(letters[1:n_grp2], each = n_grp),
               grp2 = rep(1:n_grp, times = n_grp2),
               y = runif(n_grp * n_grp2))
```

Using my function:

```
tmp_df %>%
    group_by(grp) %>%
    inner_join_grp(tmp_df_2 %>% 
                   group_by(grp), 
               by = "grp2")
```

Produces the expected fifteen row table:

```
# A tibble: 15 x 4
# Groups:   grp [?]
   grp    grp2      x      y
   <fct> <int>  <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 a         1 0.897  0.770 
 2 a         2 0.266  0.498 
 3 a         3 0.372  0.718 
 4 a         4 0.573  0.992 
 5 a         5 0.908  0.380 
...
```

whereas using `dplyr::inner_join` produces a 45 row table since the join is only on `grp2`:

```
# A tibble: 45 x 5
# Groups:   grp.x [?]
   grp.x  grp2     x grp.y      y
   <fct> <int> <dbl> <fct>  <dbl>
 1 a         1 0.897 a     0.770 
 2 a         1 0.897 b     0.777 
 3 a         1 0.897 c     0.267 
...
```

**My question is whether is possible to achieve something similar using `[`**, when the input data tables are keyed. I know I can overload `merge.data.table` (see below for a rough example) in the same way but I would prefer to pass an additional argument to `[` to achieve a keyed join.

```
merge_dt_keyed <- 
    function (x, y, by = NULL, by.x = NULL, by.y = NULL, all = FALSE, 
          all.x = all, all.y = all, sort = TRUE, 
          suffixes = c(".x", ".y"), 
          allow.cartesian = getOption("datatable.allow.cartesian"), 
          ...){

        stopifnot(identical(key(x), key(y)))



    new_key <- key(x)


    by.x <- c(new_key, by, by.x)
    by.y <- c(new_key, by, by.y)

    return(merge(x, y, by.x = by.x, by.y = by.y, all = FALSE, 
            all.x = all, all.y = all, sort = TRUE, 
            suffixes = c(".x", ".y"), 
            allow.cartesian = getOption("datatable.allow.cartesian"), 
            ...))

}
```

Comment: Why not just `dplyr::inner_join(tmp_df, tmp_df_2, by=c("grp","grp2"))`? It doesn't answer your question of how to overload `[.data.table`, but it might be a much simpler approach (and the result is effectively identical). (It doesn't hurt that it's 4-5x faster than your function, though I realize if you can do it in `data.table`, you might be able to enjoy some of its speed benefits.)

Comment: mainly it's because the groups in the input tables are flexible and possibly not known before hand.

Comment: `inner_join(tmp_df, tmp_df_2, by=intersect(colnames(tmp_df), colnames(tmp_df_2))`? Perhaps I'm trying too hard. But I see you need this functionality in `data.table`-native instead. Does `dtplyr` provide this?

Comment: my function is just a wrapper which achieves something similar to your `by = intersect(...)`.

Comment: Is `by <- c("grp2"); tmp_df[tmp_df_2, on=c(key(tmp_df),by)]` essentially all you want to do?

Comment: @thelatemail essentially, but I can't work out how to pass an additional argument.. e.g. `[..., keyed_join = T]` to the `[` operator so that your function is evaluated. (It should also be compatible with the other data table join functions like `roll` etc...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something along these lines should work:

```
`[.data.table` = function(x, i, ...) {
  args = match.call()
  if ('on' %in% names(args)) {
    args[['on']] = union(args[['on']], intersect(key(x), key(i)))
  }
  args[[1]] = data.table:::`[.data.table`
  eval(args)
}
```